# Triplet Codility in C - getting only 11 % (Training)

Tags: c

I am quite new to C and learning it partly also by going through Codility training.

For the triplet question, however I am only getting 11 % I am not sure what is wrong here. The question is: A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. The product of triplet (P, Q, R) equates to A[P] * A[Q] * A[R] (0 ≤ P < Q < R < N).

Your goal is to find the maximal product of any triplet.

Write a function:

```
int solution(int A[], int N);
```

that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A, returns the value of the maximal product of any triplet. 
For example, given array A such that:

```
A[0] = -3
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 2
A[3] = -2
A[4] = 5
A[5] = 6
```

the function should return 60, as the product of triplet (2, 4, 5) is maximal.

Assume that: 
•N is an integer within the range [3..100,000];
 •each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000..1,000].

Complexity: 
•expected worst-case time complexity is O(N*log(N));
 •expected worst-case space complexity is O(1), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

My Code which gives me 11 % is, I want to know where I am going wrong with this in this code. I first sort the matrix and then compare the three largest positive numbers and 2 largest negative together with largest positive:

```
int solution(int A[], int N) {
    int i,j,PQR_pos,PQR_neg, temp;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++) { 
        for (j=0; j<N-i; j++) 
            if (A[j+1] < A[j]) { /* compare the two neighbours */ 
                temp = A[j]; /* swap a[j] and a[j+1] */ 
                A[j] = A[j+1]; 
                A[j+1] = temp; 
            } 
    }

    PQR_pos = A[N] * A[N-1] * A[N-2];
    PQR_neg = A[N] * A[1] * A[0];

    if (PQR_pos>PQR_neg) return PQR_pos;
    else return PQR_neg;

}
```

Comment: Surely `PQR_neg` should equal `A[0] * A[1] * A[2];`

Comment: Do you think `A[N]` is valid ?

Comment: The logic is that its the 3 largest number of the array or the 2 largest negatives (becomes + ) and the largest positive...so the solution should be good ?

Comment: Looking at the solution in python it looks like i am doing the same thing;http://codesays.com/2014/solution-to-max-product-of-three-by-codility/

Comment: Paul what do you m ean....A[N] is sorted with the highest number.

Comment: In C the valid indices of an array of size `N`, are `0` through `N-1`. By writing `A[N]` you access out of the array's bounds (which is undefined behaviour).   I think the other posters didn't explicitly say this to avoid "spoilers", but it seems to me that the goal of the exercise is to get you developing a correct algorithm, not being trapped on language syntax.

Comment: i only get 77% if anyone can help me appreciated. i think i have missed one extreme case. @PaulR 

https://codility.com/demo/results/demoUHJ4AH-UQB/

Answer (score 8):

You don't need sorting at all.

First perform a linear scan of input array and store the 3 biggests and 2 lowests (and less than zero), then the result is:
  max( 
`biggest` * `2nd_biggest` * `3rd_biggest` ,

`biggest` * `lowest` * `2nd_lowest`)

Using the fact that all numbers are in [-1000..1000] you don't even need coding. Just count in array and store biggest and lowest index, after scanning input array just scan counting array to find all 5 needed numbers.

Comment: Actually, this answer is wrong, and it is wrong for this input set  `[-5, -6, -4, -7, -10]`

Comment: In order to make it work, this function would need to be adjusted to `biggest * min(2nd_biggest*3rd_biggest, lowest*2nd_lowest)` in the circumstances that biggest is negative.

Comment: @boatcoder Your example is wrong. Since all are negatives, the biggest triplet (closest to 0) would be the one composed of the smallest negative integers (so it's closer to 0). The logic above provided in the original answer works for this.

Answer (score 7):

The quiz in Codility is under "Sorting" category therefore it intentionally requires using sorting. Sorted array makes the quiz trivial. Here is the answer which meets the performance constraints O(N*LogN) time and O(1) space.

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    if(A.size() < 3) return 0;
    if(A.size() == 3) return A[0]*A[1]*A[2];
    size_t last = A.size()-1;
    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    return max(A[0]*A[1]*A[last], A[last]*A[last-1]*A[last-2]);
}
```

Comment: This answer avoids the problem with @qulinxao's answer by doing the max over the triplet.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is not necessary related to the question but it might be useful for some of you.

My solution in **Java** with **100%** is the following:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        int n = A.length;

        int maxWithNegativeNumbers = A[0] * A[1] * A[n - 1];
        int maxWithPositiveNumbers = A[n - 3] * A[n - 2] * A[n - 1];

        return Math.max(maxWithNegativeNumbers, maxWithPositiveNumbers);
    }
}
```

You need to add the following import as well:

```
 import java.util.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are learning, I assume you don't want a complete answer. So I am going with two hints.

The first one has been pointed out by Paul R :

> Do you think A[N] is valid ?

Another one is, what is the worst-case time complexity of this part (It is not O(N*log(N))) :

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) { 
    for (j=0; j<N-i; j++) 
        if (A[j+1] < A[j]) { /* compare the two neighbours */ 
            temp = A[j]; /* swap a[j] and a[j+1] */ 
            A[j] = A[j+1]; 
            A[j+1] = temp; 
        } 
}
```

### About complexity

You basically have to count how many time the comparison between two elements is done.

You have 2 loops :

- The outer one will execute `N` times the inner one
- The inner one execute the comparison `N-i` times.

So, at the first run of the outer loop, you will do, `N-0` comparison, then `N-1`, then `N-2`, [...], and finally `N - (N-1) = 1` Comparison.

So, it will make, `N + (N-1) + (N-2) + ... + 1` comparison. This is a [known summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) of `N(N+1)/2`.

So the complexity is `O(N(N+1)/2)` which is equal to `O(N^2)` ([big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation))

### About sorting algorithm

I suggest you look to faster sorting algorithm, like merge sort or quicksort. The merge sort is, in my humble opinion, easier to understand.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for some pointers, escpecially about the array size....so my N is basically N-1....Now I know why I wasnt scoring high with array questions. I dont completely get this worst-case time complexity thing yet....But I dont know how else to sort an array in C

Comment: btw, now I dont need to sort this one....but I am curious....I found so many examples of mergesort but dont get them completely or they dont work for my example...if for example I have a array 0-N, how do I build up the merge sort algorithm ? Do you have a good example ?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby Code that got 100/100 on codility

```
def solution(a)
  a.sort!
  if a[a.length - 1] >= 0
    a[a.length - 1] * ([a[0] * a[1] ,a[a.length - 2] * a[a.length - 3]].max) 
  else
    a[a.length - 1] * a[a.length - 2] * a[a.length - 3]
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

OK guys thank you very much for the help so far...I am still wondering how to implement merge sort in this function (although not needed)....so I got 100 %, this is my code:

```
int solution(int A[], int N) {
int i,N1,N2,N3,NEG1,NEG2,PQR_neg,PQR_pos;

N1=-1000;
N2=-1000;
N3=-1000;

NEG1=0;
NEG2=0;

for (i = 0; i <= (N-1); i++) 
{
    if (A[i] < NEG1 ) {
        NEG2=NEG1;
        NEG1=A[i];
    }
    else if (A[i] < NEG2) {
        NEG2=A[i];
    }
    if (A[i] > N1) {
        N3=N2; 
        N2=N1; 
        N1=A[i];
    }
    else if (A[i] > N2) {
        N3=N2;
        N2=A[i];
    }
    else if (A[i] > N3) {
        N3=A[i];
    }
}


PQR_neg = N1*NEG1*NEG2;
PQR_pos = N1*N2*N3;

if (PQR_pos>PQR_neg) return PQR_pos;
else return PQR_neg;

}
```

Comment: You could use any of the sorting algorithms provided by the standard libray ( [qsort,mergesort,heapsort](https://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/stdlib.h/qsort.php?alias=mergesort) )

Answer (score 0):

```
int solution(int A[]) {
        int k = 0;
        int d = 0;
        /*
         * int p = 0; int q = 0;
         */
        int p = 0;
        int q = 1;
        int r = -1;
        int finalValue = -1;

        for (int i = 1; i < A.length - 2; i++) {

            if (A[q] < A[p]) {
                if (k != 1) {
                    p = i - 1;
                    q = i;
                }
                if (A[i + 1] > A[i]) {

                    r = i + 1;
                    k = 0;
                    if (i + 2 < A.length - 1 && A[i + 2] > A[i + 1]) {
                        r = -1;
                        k = 1;
                    }

                } else {
                    if (A[i + 1] < A[i]) {

                        q = i + 1;
                        r = -1;
                        k = 1;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                p = i;
                q = i + 1;
            }
            if (p != -1 && q != -1 && r != -1) {
                finalValue = Math.max(finalValue, Math.min(A[p] - A[q], A[r]
                        - A[q]));
                p = 0;
                q = 1;
                r = -1;
            }
            // if (finalValue > finalWalaValue)
            // finalWalaValue = finalValue;
        }

        return finalValue;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working 100%, tested with different scenarios also.

```
// Function to remove the element 
    public int[] removeTheElement(int[] arr, int index) 
    { 
        // Create another array of size one less 
        int[] anotherArray = new int[arr.length - 1]; 

        // Copy the elements except the index 
        // from original array to the other array 
        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 

            // if the index is 
            // the removal element index 
            if (i == index) { 
                continue; 
            } 

            // if the index is not 
            // the removal element index 
            anotherArray[k++] = arr[i]; 
        } 

        //Java >8
        //IntStream.range(0, arr.length).filter(i -> i != index).map(i -> arr[i]).toArray();

        return anotherArray;
    }

    //MaxProductOfThree
    //A[P] * A[Q] * A[R] (0 <= P < Q < R < N).
    public String maxProductOfThreeSolution(int[] A) {
        long prod = 0;
        String arryVal = "";
        for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
            int[] B = removeTheElement(A, i);
            for(int j=0; j<B.length; j++) {
                int[] C = removeTheElement(B, j);
                for(int k=0; k<C.length; k++) {
                    System.out.println(A[i] +":" +B[j]+":" +C[k] +"---->"+ (A[i] * B[j] * C[k]));
                    long sum = A[i] * B[j] * C[k];
                    if(sum >= prod) {
                        prod = sum;
                        arryVal = "Array index "+i+":"+j+":"+k+", Array index value "+A[i] +":" +B[j]+":" +C[k]+"";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return prod +": "+arryVal;
    }

int[] g = {-3,1,2,-2,5,6};
        System.out.println("Max Product Of Three : "+obj.maxProductOfThreeSolution(g));
```

**Output**

Max Product Of Three : 60: Array index 5:4:2, Array index value 6:5:2

Answer (score 0):

Another on python solution O(N*log(N)) 100 / 100

```
def solution(A):
# write your code in Python 3.6
    if len(A) < 3:
        return 0
    elif len(A) == 3:
        return A[0]*A[1]*A[2]

    A.sort()
    max_negative_d = A[0] * A[1]
    max_negative_t = A[-1] * A[-2] * A[-3]
    return max(A[-1] * max(A[-2] * A[-3], max_negative_d), max_negative_t) 
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple version of the code:
The behind logic is simple supposed we have a len(A)>=3, if we sort it in reversed order we would have:
[+X, some positive numbers or 0 ... , some negative numbers]

in case of all positive numbers products of 3 first (largest) elements is the answer (max1), otherwise the we might have some negative numbers as well so for getting largest results we must have the two negative numbers (for positive results) and one biggest positive number (max2).
other cases will cover by comparing these two max values:

```
def solution(A):
    n = len(A)
    A.sort(reverse=True)
    max1 = (A[0] * A[1] * A[2])
    max2 = (A[0] * A[n-1] * A[n-2])

    return max(max1, max2)
```

Answer (score 0):

100/100 JavaScript solution

```
function solution(A) {
    A.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    let l = A.length;
    if (A[l - 1] > -1) {
        return A[l - 1] * (Math.max(...[A[0] * A[1], A[l - 2] * A[l - 3]]))
    } else {
        return A[l - 1] * (Math.min(...[A[0] * A[1], A[l - 2] * A[l - 3]]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

All, I am thinking,
**(0 ≤ P < Q < R < N).** this condition is just a trap.
The main goal of the solution is to find the top 3 highest values in the array, the sequence will be arranged automatically.

***Guys, this is the solution I found, using Javascript Code.***

```
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// console.log('this is a debug message');

function solution(A) {
    // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
    A.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
    //console.log("A",A);

    let p = A[A.length-3];
    let q = A[A.length-2];
    let r = A[A.length-1];

    return p*q*r;

}
```

Have a happy learning.
Cheers.